# Comparing elements in line

Tags: python

I have data like this

```
contig34706   sp|A1IVM0|A1IVM0_TRIDB  96
contig118453  sp|A1IVM0|A1IVM0_TRIDB  98
contig12943   tr|A7XPA0|A7XPA0_TRIDB  96    
contig92741   tr|A7XPA0|A7XPA0_TRIDB  96    
contig92741   tr|A8QU19|A8QU19_TRIDB  94
contig523     tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB  94    
contig14487   tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB  95
contig80716   tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB  93
```

I would like to know how many contigs and proteins are there in file, but obviously not considering the repetitive elements, so I thought to compare elements in line[1] to each other and count and print elements, but the ones that repeat. The same for line[0].

```
import re
count = 0
lines = open("file.txt", "r").readlines()
for line in lines:
    new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line.strip())
    contig=new_list[0]
    protien=new_list[1]
    for element in contig:
        if element != element:
            count += 1
        else:
```

well, I dont know how to finish and if this is a right way...
my desired output

```
 sp|A1IVM0|A1IVM0_TRIDB  96
 tr|A7XPA0|A7XPA0_TRIDB  96        
 tr|A8QU19|A8QU19_TRIDB  94
 tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB  94
```

Comment: can you put the expected output, that will explain a lot :)

Comment: sp|A1IVM0|A1IVM0_TRIDB  96
sp|A5A8T8|A5A8T8_TRIDB  98
tr|A7XPA0|A7XPA0_TRIDB  96    
tr|A8QTZ7|A8QTZ7_TRIDB  94    
tr|A8QU19|A8QU19_TRIDB  94                     tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB  94    
like this, without getting chatactes that repeat

Comment: please put as a part of your question, so everyone will see.

Comment: I cnahged some data to make it clearer..

Comment: If you are trying to print out the lines in a non-repetitive way to facilitate counting using human eyes, perhaps it's better to just let the code do the counting?

Comment: please let me know if my answer is not corect, so i will remove it, i don't want mislead someone :)

Comment: @YS-L I cannot count using human eyes since I have huge data, I just wanted to know which and how many contigs have hits out of n.of contigs I actually have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how many contigs and proteins are there in file

This is a way of doing it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
count_contig = defaultdict(int)
count_protein = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        count_contig[line[0]] += 1
        count_protein[line[1]] += 1
print 'Number of unique contigs:', len(count_contig)
print 'Number of unique proteins:', len(count_protein)
```

Output:

> Number of unique contigs: 7
>
> Number of unique proteins: 6

You can access the actual number of occurrence of each contigs / protein like this:

```
count_contig['contig92741'] # returns 2
count_contig['unknown_contig'] # returns 0, thanks to defaultdict
```

To list the unique number of contigs / protein, just access the keys of the dictionaries:

```
print 'Unique contigs are:', count_config.keys()
print 'Unique protens are:', count_protein.keys()
```

Output:

> Unique contigs are: ['contig12943', 'contig523', 'contig80716', 'contig118453', 'contig14487', 'contig34706', 'contig92741']
>
> Unique protens are: ['tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB', 'tr|A7XPA0|A7XPA0_TRIDB', 'tr|A8QU19|A8QU19_TRIDB', 'sp|A1IVM0|A1IVM0_TRIDB', 'sp|A5A8T8|A5A8T8_TRIDB', 'tr|A8QTZ7|A8QTZ7_TRIDB']

[Dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is wonderful and you should try to learn more about it.

Comment: amazing answer!! thank you! What if I want it to print the names of the unique contigs and proteins?

Comment: For counting things there is a `Counter` in `collections`. Just replace the `defaultdict(int)` with that.

Answer (score 2):

```
track=()
lines = open("file.txt", "r").readlines()
for line in lines:
    new_list=line.split()
    if new_list[1] not in track:
        print new_list[1]," ", new_list[2]
        track = (track, new_list[1])
```

If line[2] is new, it's printed and added to tuple to track duplicate.

Output:

```
sp|A1IVM0|A1IVM0_TRIDB   96
tr|A7XPA0|A7XPA0_TRIDB   96
tr|A8QU19|A8QU19_TRIDB   94
tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB   94
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dc, dp = {}, {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        v = line.split()
        dc[v[0]] = dp[v[1]] = 1 
print len(dc), len(dp)
for k in dc: print k
for k in dp: print k
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always return a `dict` with the the counts of each:

```
contigs = """contig34706   sp|A1IVM0|A1IVM0_TRIDB  96
contig118453  sp|A1IVM0|A1IVM0_TRIDB  98
contig12943   tr|A7XPA0|A7XPA0_TRIDB  96    
contig92741   tr|A7XPA0|A7XPA0_TRIDB  96    
contig92741   tr|A8QU19|A8QU19_TRIDB  94
contig523     tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB  94    
contig14487   tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB  95
contig80716   tr|A9U8G7|A9U8G7_TRIDB  93"""

from collections import Counter

contigs = [c.split()[1] for c in contigs.split("\n")]
contig_cnts = Counter(contigs)
```

Or even a `set` if you don't care about the counts:

```
contig_set = set(contigs)
```

Comment: it says 'cannot import name Counter', however works with 'defaultdict', is it due to python version?

Comment: @user3224522 Yes, [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is new to py2.7+ If you're using anything earlier than python2.7 it won't be in there.  Although you could easily make this [bag recipe] (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/259174/) from activestate to have the same behavior as the `Counter`